# Initial login page not showing when using spring boot security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I try to add spring boot security dependency to my blog system. Before adding spring boot security, the initial view is displayed just like my codes. But when I add configuration file of spring boot security like below,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BlogWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.configure(auth);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.configure(http);
    }

}
```

Some wired initial login view is shown.

[image]

How can I remove this initial login view so I can display my initial view.html? Is there any option to remove this login view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that is default of spring security. You should modify the overridden method `configure` depending on your need.

You can read [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login) on how to implement spring security with custom configuration.

For example:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                // add your resources here. By default, spring security blocks all resources that is not under /resources/**
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/images/**").permitAll()
                // prevent spring security from blocking some pages that doesn't require authentication to be access here.
                .antMatchers("/forgot-password", "/change-password").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            // login configuration
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login") // can either be mapping or file
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            // logout configuration
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .permitAll();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My issue is automatic redirection of home url. My first view url is "http://localhost:8080/home". But when I add those classes, the initial url is redirected to "http://localhost:8080/login". I found the "security.basic.enabled" option by googling. But I am afraid the option was deprecated. Any advice?

Comment: like what i've said, you are being redirected on spring security's default login page. Look at my exaple, make your home page public by adding the mapping of your home page to .antMatchers("/home").permitAll()

Comment: I have just given you an example, you can just customize it depending on your need. if your just need to redirect to your home page add cofiguration with something like this:

http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/home*").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()